# unable to display a dialog using remote.dialog() or do an IPC in electron/angular-cli app

Tags: webpack, electron, angular-cli

I am trying to show dialogs from renderer process. While googling, i found out that i have to `const dialog = remote.dialog`. when trying to `dialog.showErrorBox("error","this is error")`, I get an error in the renderer module `fs.existsSync is not a function`. Please let me know how to show dialogs in the renderer process. I tried, doing a IPC call to the main function. But, still when I call `ipcRenderer.send()` or `ipcRenderer.sendSync()`, i get the same error `fs.existsSync is not a function`. my bootstrapfile.ts file is as follows:

```
import { enableProdMode, Provider } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from '/path/to/app.module';
import {remote} from 'electron';
remote.dialog.showErrorBox("Error", "An error occured");

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, ... )
```

Here is the stack trace on the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:505)
    at Object.../../../../electron/index.js (vendor.bundle.js:511)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)                
    at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.bundle.js:1507)
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)                
    at Object.1 (main.bundle.js:1531)                           
    at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)                
    at webpackJsonpCallback (inline.bundle.js:26)               
    at main.bundle.js:1
```

I tried to debug what's happening. I noticed the following in the main.bundle.js and vendor.bundle.js
at frame `at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.bundle.js:1507)` of the stack trace, the generated code is as follows:

```
/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_electron__ = __webpack_require__("../../../../electron/index.js");
```

And at frame `at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:505)` the generated code is

```
var fs = __webpack_require__("../../../../node-libs-browser/mock/empty.js");
if (fs.existsSync(pathFile)) {....}
```

clearly, the variable `fs` is empty and it is resulting in an exception. I am not sure what is happening here. Could some one please help me understand what's happening and what am i going wrong here? I would also like to know how to display dialogs from an electron/angular-cli application.

Comment: I solved this. This is how you do it in typescript

Comment: What is how you do it in TypeScript?

Comment: @ScubaKay: Here's what i did.
    import {electron} from electron;
    const remote = electron.remote;
    const fs = remote.require('fs');
    fs.existsSync(); // works